# C# records having class properties, how do they work?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I am reading a lot about records and the new features in C# 9 and 10. I understand that records are reference types with some magic for equality so they should behave like value types. I now love to use `record` for models with simple properties.

What about such a model:

```
public record MyRecord
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> MyDictionary { get; init; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

I am not sure to understand if there are benefits of using `record` when one of the property is a class (the dictionary). I would like to learn as much as possible on the specific case of using class properties within a record, the implications, etc.

Comment: Records are intended to speed up the writing of reference types that have value semantics (which, in C#, pretty much means value equality). You use a record when you want to save time writing `Equals` and related things. It's hard to tell if you would really benefit from a record here with such a generic example. You should try to explain what you're really trying to do a bit better.

Comment: As @EtiennedeMartel notes. *But also* for quick data only types using a primary constructor rather than explicitly specifying a set of properties.

Comment: Or, in short, `public record MyRecord(Dictionary<string,string> MyDictionary);`

Comment: *using class properties within a record* - you never made a record with a string property?

Comment: *I would like to learn as much as possible* - this isn't a question, and *"how do they work?"* is too vague. Please have a think about what your question actually is, and consider rephrasing the words above to be more targeted

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, but I thought then that two instances of such a record would need both strings to have the same value to be considered equal? Do you mean I understood that wrong, and since string is a reference type, two records with a string property would need to reference the *same* string (memory address) to be considered equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [C# Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#value-equality) and the [Specification for `record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records):

> For `record` types, including `record struct` and `readonly record struct`, two objects are equal if they are of the same type and store the same values.

> The record type implements `System.IEquatable<R>` and includes a synthesized strongly-typed overload of `Equals(R? other)` where `R` is the record type.
>
> ...
>
> The synthesized Equals(R?) returns true if and only if each of the
> following are true:
>
> - `other` is not null, and
> - For each instance field `fieldN` in the record type that is not inherited, the value of
>   `System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<TN>.Default.Equals(fieldN, other.fieldN)` where `TN` is the field type, and
> - If there is a base record type, the value of `base.Equals(other)` (a non-virtual call to `public virtual bool Equals(Base? other)`);
>   otherwise the value of `EqualityContract == other.EqualityContract`.

Since the definition for "equal" for a dictionary is reference equality by default, two of your records would be "equal" if and only if they reference the *same* dictionary. There is no built-in mechanism to ensure that the dictionaries contain the same keys and values (which is what it seems like you're wanting).